# Handing multiple email HTMLs in a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-email

We are implementing an email support application. As in any other support application, the customer can send multiple emails in a thread or chain. This chain can also include replies from the agent, who is working on resolving the case. The HTML display, in this case, is structured as below,

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
         EMAIL 1 - This has it's entire HTML content. Including Body css etc etc.
    </div>   
    <div>
         EMAIL 2 - This has it's entire HTML content. Including Body css etc etc.
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem we are facing is these emails come with their own HTML content. This is causing in many cases conflict with our HTML structure or CSS or both. Resulting in the page to break in structure or for the CSS to get miss represented.

We tried putting these individual mails in an iframe, but that's causing the page-load to become very slow or unresponsive when there are multiple emails in a thread.

```
<iframe id="html_content" style="overflow:hidden;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%"  onload="this.height=this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight+20 + 'px';"  srcdoc="<div>{{htmlContent}}</div>"></iframe>
```

Any suggestions on how this could be handled best and reduce conflict with our page css or html structure would help.

Comment: Maybe you need to change all the css code from each of the shown emails, to only apply in that div/iframe.. Set an ID on the iframe, and change all css to iframe#email1 body, iframe#email1 td, etc for that email, so it dosnt change anything in your parent view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do what Gmail etc. do and modify the code before it's inserted into the page.

You can reverse-engineer their emails by looking at the output code from within a robust email client. (See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33926/can-i-view-the-html-source-of-an-email-sent-to-my-gmail-address for Gmail source code.)

To avoid CSS clashes, you will essentially need to prefix all incoming CSS classes.

To avoid HTML clashes, you'll need to disallow certain properties (or only allow some). For example, you won't want fixed positioning. Absolute positioning may require your wrapping div to be positioned relatively.

You need to change the `<body>` tags to a `<div>`.

You need to remove the `<html>` tag, and `<meta>` tags, after you've interpreted them. I.e. some `<meta>` tags contain instructions like "this email accepts dark mode", or, "this email only accepts light mode" - and you'll need to interpret accordingly, if you think you need to do anything with them. You might be able to safely ignore them (remove them) for a first version.

You may want to insert lazy loading functioning so that only certain content gets loaded at a time - particularly images and other assets (although typically it is expected that external stylesheets get stripped, since you can't ensure they won't interfere).

For security and non-interference, you need to remove `<script>` tags.

For mobiles, I've noticed that there is some sort of detection for responsiveness, and if the email is not responsive, the email software will add something like a transform: scale (0.xx) to the outer wrapper(s) so that it fits. Deal with that how you like.

Comment: is there any library available which helps us achieve this. Just looking for a shortcut :)

Comment: I'm not certain of your overall workflow, but while it's a string it's difficult to use regex for things like this. People will tell you, for good reason, regex can't parse HTML. BUT, you may be able to do these simple things with it. So, obviously, not a library - but could be easier. 

Alternatively, jQuery is able to do this easily if you can load it into the DOM and subsequently make the changes, and then re-save as a string.